# Google Map api doesn't gives lat/long on exact address c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude from address text using google map api.

Here is code, that I have tried.

First:

```
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(business.Address2);

var latitude = point.Latitude;
var longitude = point.Longitude;
```

Second:

```
IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder() { };
Address[] addresses = geocoder.Geocode(business.Address2).ToArray();
foreach (Address adrs in addresses)
{
    var test = adrs.Coordinates;
}
```

Third:

```
public RootObject GetLatLongByAddress(string address)
{
    var root = new RootObject();

    var url =string.Format(
                    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=true_or_false", address);
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
           root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
         }
    }
        return root;
 }
```

And my address string is  *"Ground Floor, Nishika Avenue, Swastik Char Rasta, Navrangpura, Opposite Narnarayan Complex, Ahmadabad"*

I've tried with all though, but it not gives me latitude and longitude anyway.

When I remove first part of my address string (i.e *Navrangpura, Opposite Narnarayan Complex, Ahmadabad*) and try, it's give me lat/long.

But when I search with full address on [Google Map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/ViP+Exclusive/@23.0314643,72.5619191,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x395e84f53fffffff:0x231918bf9c49c4e2!8m2!3d23.0314594!4d72.5641078) it shows the result.

Why this is so? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The address 'Ground Floor, Nishika Avenue, Swastik Char Rasta, Navrangpura, Opposite Narnarayan Complex, Ahmadabad' cannot be found at maps.google.com as well

[image]

The API cannot find something that doesn't exist. You should add this place via maps.google.com or format your address string better following the

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is available on Google Map please kindly check the link from the question which pointed out the result'